# How to use querySelectorAll to get all children of a parent excluding only one child in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div with a lot of content with the class `print` inside  , there is a `<tr>` element with the class `.ignore-me` , now I want to get all the items inside the div, but not the item with class name `.ignore-me` here how I tried it :

```js
    var theHtml=document.querySelectorAll(".print >:not(.ignore-me)");
    theHtml.forEach(ele=>console.log(ele.innerHTML));
```

But the result includes every item in the div without excluding the `.ignore-me`

Comment: You need to show a minimal example of the HTML structure. Including one example that should be in the result and one with the class `ignore-me` and the desired result. A `tr` can never be a child of a `div` it can only be a descendant.

Comment: Side note: What `querySelectorAll` returns is a `NodeList` of matching `HTMLElement` (or subclass) objects, not HTML. `theHtml` is an odd name for that... I only mention it because when I see people thinking of the DOM as HTML, it tends to lead them astray. The DOM is not HTML. It's the *result* of *parsing* HTML (usually).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that the `.ignore-me` element isn't a direct child of the `.print` `div`. So you'll want to remove the `>`, because that only excludes it if it's a direct child:

```
var theHtml=document.querySelectorAll(".print :not(.ignore-me)");
```

Example:

```js
var theHtml=document.querySelectorAll(".print :not(.ignore-me)");
console.log(`Length: ${theHtml.length}`);
theHtml.forEach(el => {
    const cls = el.className ? `.${el.className.replace(/ /g, ".")}` : "";
    const id = el.id ? `#${el.id}` : "";
    console.log(el.tagName + id + cls);
});
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="print">
        <div class="x">x</div>
        <div class="y">
            y
            <div class="ignore-me">ignore</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note, though, that it matters what you're *doing* with the elements that you select. For instance, if you look at `innerHTML` on (say) `div.y` above, you'll see the `.ignore-me` element, because it's in that `div.y` element. It's not in the list, though.